# Consider all the variables created in a for loop as a vector, e.g. `c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10)`

Tags: r, for-loop, variables

This code:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    assign(paste0('x', i), i)
}
```

creates 10 variables in a for loop. I would like to consider all these variables in a vector, e.g.

```
c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10)
```

Comment: What is the question? Your code creates a vector from the 10 variables. Depending on what you are planning to do, simply creating the vector and skipping the loop would be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved with a combination of `ls` and `mget`.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    assign(paste0('x', i), i)
}

x_vars <- ls(pattern = "^x\\d+$", envir = .GlobalEnv)
x_all <- mget(x_vars, envir = .GlobalEnv)
x_all <- sort(unlist(x_all))
x_all 
# x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9 x10 
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

I am assuming the vector elements must be in the same order they were created in the `for` loop.
Or, without creating `x_vars`:

```
x_all <- mget(ls(pattern = "^x\\d+$", envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
x_all <- sort(unlist(x_all))
```

Answer (score 0):

No loop needed. Why not just name a vector of values>

```
 x_all <- 1:10
 names(x_all) <- paste0("x", x_all)
 x_all
#----------------
 x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9 x10 
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

Answer (score 0):

an option with `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
 names(x_all) <- str_c("x", x_all)
```